# Flex drag and drop reorder of a HorizontalList control - Finding FROM and TO indexes?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, drag-and-drop

I have a Flex3 project with 2 HorizontalList controls; one of which has drag & drop enabled. Both controls will always have the same number of items, and are related... index 0 from the 1st control matches index 0 from the 2nd control, and so on.

Naturally, when using drag and drop to reorder the 2nd control, I want the items in the 1st control to reflect the same reordering. I think I can handle the actual updating of the control, but I'm having trouble finding the **from** and **to** indexes of the item that has been moved via drag & drop.

Using the `dragDrop` method on the control that allows drag and drop, and perusing the contents of `event.currentTarget` (instead of `event.target` [because the docs say so](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:dragDrop)) in the debugger shows a public property named `selectedIndex` which does seem to hold the **from** index, but I don't see any properties that will tell me the **to** index.

Am I overlooking the property? Do I have to infer it based on something else? Is there a better way to do this?

**update:** An acceptable solution might also be to iterate over the contents of the HorizontalList and save the internal index value to an array that could then be used to re-sort the dataProvider for the other list; but I can't figure out how to iterate over the list contents, so I'm just as stuck. Any help there?

Here's my code:

`main.mxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    xmlns:com="components.*"
    layout="absolute" 
>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.DragEvent;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            //these two variables are junk data to represent 
            //what we will get back from our data services...
            [Bindable] 
            private var btnData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
                [
                    {title:'title1', index:0},
                    {title:'title2', index:1},
                    {title:'title3', index:2},
                    {title:'title4', index:3}
                ]
            );
            [Bindable] 
            private var chainData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
                [
                    {tmp:'testing 1'},
                    {tmp:'testing 2'},
                    {tmp:'testing 3'},
                    {tmp:'testing 4'}
                ]
            );

            //handle button re-ordering
            private function handleBtnReorder(event:DragEvent):void{
                Alert.show(event.action.toString());
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HorizontalList
        id="ChainView"
        dataProvider="{chainData}"
        itemRenderer="components.ItemRenderers.ChainLinkRenderer"
        left="20"
        right="20"
        top="20"
        height="300"
        rowHeight="300"
        columnWidth="500"
        rollOverColor="#ffffff"
        selectionColor="#eeeeee"
    />

    <mx:HorizontalList 
        id="btnList" 
        dataProvider="{btnData}"
        dragEnabled="true" 
        dropEnabled="true"
        dragMoveEnabled="true"
        dragDrop="handleBtnReorder(event)"
        itemRenderer="components.ItemRenderers.BtnListRenderer"
        horizontalCenter="true"
        left="20"
        right="20"
        top="320"
        height="50"
        rowHeight="35"
        rollOverColor="#ffffff"
        selectionColor="#ffffff"
    />

</mx:Application>
```

The `Alert.show(...)` isn't there to show anything useful, I've set a breakpoint on that line so that I can inspect the event argument.

I don't think the custom itemRenderer's are important (there's not much code to them, yet), so I'll leave them out for brevity's sake. If you think they *are* important, let me know and I'll edit them in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the solution was to switch from using the `dragDrop` event to the `dragComplete` event; at which point, the binded dataProvider has been updated to reflect the reordering.

Answer (score -1):

Thats why the Model Locator pattern is made for!

You must move your dataProvider to a singleton class (Model for instance) than your item renderers can easily access to it. There is no point that your item has the property Index since its already given by a [ArrayCollection].getItemIndex(..)